# How do you cure a zombie villager?

Tags: achievements, minecraft-legacy-console

There is an achievement in the Xbox 360 of Minecraft for curing a Zombie Villager from its infection.

Is there a way to save the poor villager from its infection?

Comment: @DarkHyudrA. He could, but he wanted a better answer. Some answers in the wikipedia are written in a way that some people do not understand. I am sure he googled it before and couldn't find the answer he wanted, and so came to our Q&A site. Please be more considerate. I am sure he would not be asking this question if he already found the answer he wanted on the wikipedia.

Comment: @DetonationsPlus I know that the wiki is a mess, because there's so much content ina single page, but I'm still with my point: found this in the 5th link on google, and there's a ton more non SE sites with answers to that question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177784/how-can-i-get-a-villager-without-a-village

Comment: @DarkHyudrA. Some people understand wikipedia easily, for example, you. But there are some people that just needs a answer from that wikipedia, but summarized. Google is convenient for some people, but lets not forget, we are here to answer questions. Not drive people away from our Q&A site. If you are satisfied with the answer given in Google, its fine! We are here to give answers to people who need a summary. We are here to help people get the answers they want. We are not here to judge other people, they do what they want. We are just here to give them an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Make a Splash Potion of Weakness (use a Fermented Spider Eye and Gunpowder) and throw it at the villager. After they have that effect, feed them a regular Golden Apple (via the Use Button). In a while, they will turn back into a regular villager.

Note, though, that it's a good idea to keep the villager somewhere sheltered so he doesn't burn before he transforms.

<sup>[(src)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie#Zombie_villagers)</sup>

Comment: Also, partially cured zombie villagers can despawn if you don't keep an eye on them.